# get which button clicked on android widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-service

I have a widget whos designing is now complete and consists of 4 buttons ,I want to get which button on the widget was clicked and based on the button clicked want to pass a value to the service where I take necessary actions on it.

Comment: what you want to do.. whether u want to get the text of the button which is clicked..

Comment: I need to call a public method in another accessible class that this I have all done already but now I just need to get the onClick over the widget button and then based on the button that was clicked I call a method.

Comment: so if you get the text of the button which is clicked based on that text you can call the required method right.. if yes i ll post code for that.

Comment: yes please! you can post code example

Answer (score 0):

your code should be like this

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements  OnClickListener {
    Button btn0,btn1,btn2,btn3;

       btn0.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
     }
      @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(btnrunclick=true)
    {
        Button b = (Button)v;
        buttonText = b.getText().toString();// this will return button text which is clicked
        if(buttonText..equalsIgnoreCase("your text"))
      {
         //call required method for that button

          }
         else if(buttonText.equalsIgnoreCase("next button text"))               
    {
         //call required method for that button

          }

    }       
}
```

Comment: I need to make this happen in a Widget!

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by implementing `View.OnClickListener` & assigning it to all the 4 buttons you have like. I have not tried this yet but maybe you can give it a shot: -

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnCLickListener () {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v instanceof Button && (Button) v == btn1) {
            // Do something
        } else if (v instanceof Button && (Button) v == btn2) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
btn1.setOnClickListener(listener);
btn2.setOnClickListener(listener);
```